# How to set a custom Icon of an Outlook folder?

Tags: c#, outlook, icons, directory, outlook-2007

Is there any way to set a custom Icon of an Outlook folder or subfolder using Outlook object model?

Comment: What version of Outlook are you targeting and do you have a language that you want to use?

Comment: I am using Outlook 2007 and C#

Answer (score 3):

As from Outlook 2010 you can use `MAPIFolder.SetCUstomIcon` as described above.

I have had the same challenge recently and found a nice snippet of VBA code at
[Change Outlook folders colors possible?](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/135867-change-outlook-folders-colors-possible):

> [*joelandre*](https://community.spiceworks.com/people/joelandre) <sub>[Jan 12, 2015 at 9:13 PM](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/post/4183787)</sub>
>
> 1. Unzip the file [icons.zip](https://static.spiceworks.com/attachments/post/0016/5547/icons.zip) to C:\icons
> 2. Define the code below as Visual Basic Macros
> 3. Adapt the function ColorizeOutlookFolders according to your needs Text
>
>    ```vba
>    Function GetFolder(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.folder
>        ' Returns an Outlook folder object basing on the folder path
>        '
>        Dim TempFolder As Outlook.folder
>        Dim FoldersArray As Variant
>        Dim i As Integer
>
>        On Error GoTo GetFolder_Error
>
>        'Remove Leading slashes in the folder path
>        If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
>            FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
>        End If
>
>        'Convert folderpath to array
>        FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
>        Set TempFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
>
>        If Not TempFolder Is Nothing Then
>            For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
>                Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
>                Set SubFolders = TempFolder.Folders
>                Set TempFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
>                If TempFolder Is Nothing Then
>                    Set GetFolder = Nothing
>                End If
>            Next
>        End If
>        'Return the TempFolder
>        Set GetFolder = TempFolder
>        Exit Function   GetFolder_Error:
>        Set GetFolder = Nothing
>        Exit Function End Function   Sub ColorizeOneFolder(FolderPath As String, FolderColour As String)
>        Dim myPic As IPictureDisp
>        Dim folder As Outlook.folder
>
>        Set folder = GetFolder(FolderPath)
>        Set myPic = LoadPicture("C:\icons\" + FolderColour + ".ico")
>        If Not (folder Is Nothing) Then
>            ' set a custom icon to the folder
>            folder.SetCustomIcon myPic
>            'Debug.Print "setting colour to " + FolderPath + " as " + FolderColour
>        End If End Sub
>
>    Sub ColorizeFolderAndSubFolders(strFolderPath As String, strFolderColour As String)
>        ' this procedure colorizes the foler given by strFolderPath and all subfolfers
>
>        Dim olProjectRootFolder As Outlook.folder
>        Set olProjectRootFolder = GetFolder(strFolderPath)
>
>        Dim i As Long
>        Dim olNewFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
>        Dim olTempFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
>        Dim strTempFolderPath As String
>
>        ' colorize folder
>        Call ColorizeOneFolder(strFolderPath, strFolderColour)
>
>         ' Loop through the items in the current folder.
>        For i = olProjectRootFolder.Folders.Count To 1 Step -1
>
>            Set olTempFolder = olProjectRootFolder.Folders(i)
>
>            strTempFolderPath = olTempFolder.FolderPath
>
>             'prints the folder path and name in the VB Editor's Immediate window
>             'Debug.Print sTempFolderPath
>
>             ' colorize folder
>             Call ColorizeOneFolder(strTempFolderPath, strFolderColour)
>        Next
>
>        For Each olNewFolder In olProjectRootFolder.Folders
>            ' recursive call
>            'Debug.Print olNewFolder.FolderPath
>            Call ColorizeFolderAndSubFolders(olNewFolder.FolderPath, strFolderColour)
>        Next
>
>    End Sub
>
>    Sub ColorizeOutlookFolders()
>
>        Call ColorizeFolderAndSubFolders("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\100-People", "blue")
>        Call ColorizeFolderAndSubFolders("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\200-Projects","red")
>        Call ColorizeFolderAndSubFolders("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\500-Meeting", "green")
>        Call ColorizeFolderAndSubFolders("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\800-Product", "magenta")
>        Call ColorizeFolderAndSubFolders("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\600-Departments", "grey")
>
>        Call ColorizeFolderAndSubFolders("\\Mailbox - Dan Wilson\Inbox\Customers", "grey")
>
>
>    End Sub
>    ```
> 4. In the object ThisOutlookSession, define the following function:
>
>    ```vba
>    Private Sub Application_Startup()
>
>    ColorizeOutlookFolders
>
>    End Sub
>    ```

and

> In order to NOT color sub-folders, you can use the function
>   ColorizeOneFolder instead of ColorizeFolderAndSubFolders e.g.
>
> ```vba
> Sub ColorizeOutlookFolders()
>
>     Call ColorizeOneFolder ("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\100-People", "blue")
>     Call ColorizeOneFolder ("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\200-Projects", "red")
>     Call ColorizeOneFolder ("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\500-Meeting", "green")
>     Call ColorizeOneFolder ("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\800-Product", "magenta")
>     Call ColorizeOneFolder ("\\Personal\Documents\000-Mgmt-CH\600-Departments", "grey")
>
>     Call ColorizeOneFolder ("\\Mailbox - Dan Wilson\Inbox\Customers", "grey")
>
> End Sub
> ```
>
> When you move sub-folders between folders, they should retain their
>   color only until the next time you restart Outlook.

Comment: Since link rot may prevail, I edited in the scripts.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read this is unfortunately not possible in Outlook 2007.

It is possible in Outlook 2010 using `MAPIFolder.SetCustomIcon`.  See MSDN for more details:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184775.aspx

Switching the list of MAPIFolder methods between 2010 and 2007 on the following MSDN webpage shows the `SetCustomIcon` method for 2010 only:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb645002.aspx