# How do I set a custom icon in the Outlook explorer window for my custom item?

Tags: outlook, vsto, icons

Using Using VSTO 3.0 for Outlook 2007

I have my own item type derived from post called "IPM.Post.CustomType". However in the explorer window (the list of all items in a folder), the icon for my item is still the standard post item.

How do I make my custom item show my custom icon instead of the standard icon in the explorer window?

And related to this, how do I set change the icon for a folder in Outlook.

Comment: Are you deploy a form in the vsto ?

Answer (score 0):

1.) I think you need to use a custom form region to provide a custom icon in Outlook explorer
 view (override `GetFormRegionIcon`). See this [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177040%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

2.) You can only create custom folder icons in Outlook 2010 according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036444/how-to-set-a-custom-icon-of-an-outlook-folder/5154027#5154027).